# Matlab's Movsum() doesn't start calc at defined starting point X in [X X+t]

Tags: matlab, indexing, reference, sum

Suppose the following:

```
A = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7];
A1 = table(A);
```

[image]

The following sums current and 2 following cells beneath:

```
A2 = movsum(A1{:, 1:end}, [0 2], 'Endpoints', 'fill');`
```

What I want is the sum of what above movsum() does, but without 
considering the current cell (0 in [0 2]). The very first value of this calculation (= **first row in new table**) should be 5 (2+3), the second 7 (3+4) etc.
How do I have to adapt my following code for it to do the intended calculations?

```
A3 = movsum(A1{:, 1:end}, [1 2], 'Endpoints', 'fill');
```

... because A3 returns:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `movsum` supports this, as the help reads as

> Y = movsum(X,[NB NF]) [...] returning the local sum of the previous
>   NB elements, the current element, and the next NF elements of X.

However, a simple solution would be to subtract the unwanted current cell via

`A2 = movsum(A1{:, 1:end}, [0 2], 'Endpoints', 'fill') - A1{:, 1:end};`

Testing it gives

```
movsum(1:7,[0,2],'EndPoints','fill') - (1:7)

ans =

 5     7     9    11    13   NaN   NaN
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: does this rationale also work if I want the sum of all values, excluding the current cell + the one thereafter, @Florian? E.g. returns 3 in first row of new table

Comment: @John something like : `conv(A,[1,1],'valid')` ?

Comment: @John: In this case you could always do something like `movsum(1:7,[0,2],'EndPoints','fill') - movsum(1:7,[0,1],'EndPoints','fill')`, i.e., a difference of two movsums, where the second one takes away everything you didn't want the first one to include. Not the most efficient way of doing it but simple enough.

Comment: @Florian, the movsum()-movsum() approach returns the correct response for this particular example where the lower bound is limited by 2 in [x,2]. However my actual lower bound is at 50 and in this case movsum(..,[0,50]..) - movsum(...,[0,49],...) is wrong. Can you generalize your last idea, please?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want. If you want to exclude the current and the next but sum the second-to-next up to 50 ahead, you would do `movsum(...,[0,50], ...) - movsum(..., [0,1], ...)`. If not you need to explain which elements exactly you want to sum.